# SQL Creating new rows based on column values

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use SQL Server Management Studio to transform some Insurance Policy data from Policy table to a Driver table.

I need to create a new row for each additional driver on a policy but retain the policy level info. Ie, I need a query for this transformation...

[image]

Comment: Images of data often aren't helpful. Could you please, at least, edit your post and provide your sample as text.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your schema by normalizing it. There should be an extra driver table referencing the policy table.

Meanwhile have three `SELECT`s, one for each set of driver data columns and `UNION ALL` them together.

```
SELECT policynum,
       vehiclereg,
       make,
       maindriver_name driver_name,
       maindriver_dob driver_dob
       FROM policytable
UNION ALL
SELECT policynum,
       vehiclereg,
       make,
       add1_name driver_name,
       add1_dob driver_dob
       FROM policytable
       WHERE additionaldrivers > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT policynum,
       vehiclereg,
       make,
       add2_name driver_name,
       add2_dob driver_dob
       FROM policytable
       WHERE additionaldrivers > 1;
```